# Pandas. Exporting to Excel returns error: "Bad file descriptor" or "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, pandas

I always used the same way to export Dataframes to excel:

```
df.to_excel('file_name.xlsx', index=False, sheet_name='sheet_name')
```

To import files I define the path first and then, used a command pd.read_excel and it stil works well.

```
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\folder_1\\folder_2")
file="file_name.xlsx"
df=pd.read_excel(file)
```

But the export method stopped working
The errors returned where:

1. [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
2. [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

I have already uninstalled and installed again Anaconda.

Anybody has faced this problem before? How to fix it?

I do not know if it's relevant. In a workbook of python there is the following:

```
if not self.fileclosed:

        try:
            self._store_workbook()
        except IOError as e:
            raise FileCreateError(e)
        except LargeZipFile as e:
            raise FileSizeError("Filesize would require ZIP64 extensions. "
                                "Use workbook.use_zip64().")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the path is a litteral word "path" (as a string). Normally, it should be a variable `path` that content is the string of the path

Comment: It is as normal path "C:\\Users\\folder_1\\folder_2". I just put the word path to make it shorter. It works for importing file but for exporting

Comment: In the folder in which you run your python script, do you have a folder named `path` ?

Comment: I have changed it in the original post  to not be confused

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but try changing your path to this?

```
os.chdir(r"C:\\Users\\folder_1\\folder_2")
```

or manually test it:

```
df.to_excel(r'your_path\.xlsx')
```

and see whether it works?